# If current field (target closure date <= today AND Status = "Open"(This is drop down option)), then text should display in red color

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

If current field (target closure date) is <= today AND Status = "Open"(This is drop down option), then text should display in red color.

I have tried with below JSON but no luck:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "debugMode": true,
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if((@currentField = @now),if([$Status] == 'Open'), '#ff0000', '')" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, below is working

```
   {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Open', if([$Target_x0020_Closure_x0020_Date] <= @now,'#ff0000',''),'')"
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not working as expected. it is for only currentfield

Comment: you can use [$Status] to reference other fields....

Comment: {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Open' && [$Target_x0020_Closure_x0020_Date] <= @now , '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}

Comment: The above mentioned JSON is working as expected. Thank you to all

Comment: please check updated answer.

Comment: Please upvote and accept answer if it helped...

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **&& (AND)** operator it will work perfectly for your scenario.

Try below code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "debugMode": true,
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if(@currentField <= @now && [$Status] == 'Open', '#ff0000', '')"
    }
}
```

Check the detailed article about the operators which are currently supported in JSON formatting:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators).

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Thank you Ganesh